# .extractText() returns "invalid literal for decimal"

Tags: pypdf

I'm coding something which will read PDFs online and return a set of keywords that are found in the document. However I keep running into a problem with the `extractText()` function from the PyPDF2 package.

Here's my code to open the PDFs and read it:

```
x = myurl.pdf
if ".pdf" in x:
remoteFile = urlopen(Request(x, headers={"User-Agent": "Magic-Browser"})).read()
memoryFile = StringIO(remoteFile)
pdfFile = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(memoryFile, strict=False)
num_pages = pdfFile.numPages
count = 0
text = ""
while count < num_pages:
    pageObj = pdfFile.getPage(count)
    count += 1
    text += pageObj.extractText()
```

The error that I keep running into on the `extractText()` line goes like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "errortest.py", line 30, in <module>
    text += pageObj.extractText()
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyPDF2/pdf.py", line 2595, in extractText
    content = ContentStream(content, self.pdf)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyPDF2/pdf.py", line 2674, in __init__
    self.__parseContentStream(stream)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyPDF2/pdf.py", line 2706, in __parseContentStream
    operands.append(readObject(stream, None))
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyPDF2/generic.py", line 98, in readObject
    return NumberObject.readFromStream(stream)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyPDF2/generic.py", line 271, in readFromStream
    return FloatObject(num)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyPDF2/generic.py", line 231, in __new__
    return decimal.Decimal.__new__(cls, str(value))
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/decimal.py", line 547, in __new__
    "Invalid literal for Decimal: %r" % value)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/decimal.py", line 3872, in _raise_error
    raise error(explanation)
decimal.InvalidOperation: Invalid literal for Decimal: '99.-72'
```

Would be great if someone could help me out! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is too little information to be certain, but PyPDF2 (and now `pypdf`) improved a lot in 2022. You will probably just need to upgrade to the latest version of `pypdf`.

If you encounter a bug in `pypdf` again, please open an issue: https://github.com/py-pdf/pypdf

A good bug ticket contains (1) your pypdf version (2) the code + PDF document that caused the issue.